# urlrewriter.net page not executed

Tags: asp.net, multilingual, urlrewriter.net

I'm having some problems with the module urlrewriter.net for ASP.NET.

I have a multilingual site with a URL like this;

```
~/home.aspx
```

To support languages I use this rewrite rule;

```
<rewrite url="~/de-DE/(.*)" to="~/$1"></rewrite>
```

Then in my code I get the de-DE part and set the right culture for the current thread. All of this works well.

After I login on the website I get a message "Hello, user x" to show i'm logged in. When navigating to another page, it doesn't display this message anymore and it seems like the page comes from the cache or something with the old (not logged in) data. Also, when I attach the debugger, nothing is executed for this request. If I visit the page like ~/home.aspx instead of ~/de-DE/home.aspx, does problem does not occur.

What could be the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind!

I had accidently disabled the Check for newer pages in IE8 which caused all of the problems... I'm sorry for the useless question!

Comment: Not useless, someone may find the solution they need.  Caching is one of those necessary "evils" that keeps messing with you.